# Find a point within a distance limit from a set of points

Tags: geometry

Let's say I have a set of points, defined as $(x_1, y_1, z_1), (x_2, y_2, z_2), ..., (x_n, y_n, z_n)$. How would I go about finding another point, $p_m$, so that the Euclidean distance $d$ of $p_m$ to any other point in the set satisfies the following

$$d_{min} \le d \le d_{max}$$

where $d_{min}$ and $d_{max}$ are some arbitrary values? Is there a generalised formula to do so for any amount $n$ of points?

**Edit**

Assume that $d_{max}$ is always bigger than 0 and always bigger than $d_{min}$.

Comment: There has to be some restrictions on $d_{max}$, for instance if $d_{max}=0$, this is not possible unless all the points are the same.

Comment: @yoyostein Ok, assume that $d_{max}$ is always bigger than 0 and always bigger than $d_{min}$.

Comment: All possible $p_m$ lie in the intersection of $n$ rings all having radius $d_{min}$ to $d_{max}$. By *ring*, I'm referring to an *[annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics))*.